# Mutable fields should not be "public static"

Tags: java, arrays, collections, sonarqube

I getting sonarQube error of below line, any suggestion experts how to resolve this? Thanks in advance

```
    protected static final String [] COLUMN_NAMES = new String[]{"date","customerNumber","customerName",
            "account","emailAdress","mobilePhoneNumber","emailStatus"};
```

Comment: er make it private?

Comment: Well, what are you trying to achieve? Do you definitely have to expose the array directly? Could you expose an immutable list instead, for example?

Comment: @JonSkeet, yes it can be exposed as immutable list

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can change this array into a `private` variable.

Then add a `static` method that returns a copy of this array, or an immutable `List` backed by this array.

For example:

```
private static final String [] COLUMN_NAMES = new String[]{"date","customerNumber","customerName",
        "account","emailAdress","mobilePhoneNumber","emailStatus"};

protected static List<String> getColumnNames() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(COLUMN_NAMES));
}
```

Or you can replace the array variable with an unmodifiable `List` instead of using the method. That would be more efficient (since the `List` will be created once instead of in every call to the `static` method):

```
protected static List<String> COLUMN_NAMES = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList("date","customerNumber","customerName",
        "account","emailAdress","mobilePhoneNumber","emailStatus"));
```

Comment: can you please point me to any resource on how to do that, thanks.

Comment: `List.of` since JavaSE 9.

Comment: public  static final List<String> PROJECT_TYPES  = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList("project1","project2")); --> this is also working in jdk8 and no sonar issues

Answer (score 4):

You can make `COLUMN_NAMES` private and simply return clone of it like below:

```
private static final String [] COLUMN_NAMES = new String[]{"date","customerNumber","customerName",
        "account","emailAdress","mobilePhoneNumber","emailStatus"};

protected static String[] getCloneArray()
{
  return COLUMN_NAMES.clone();
}
```

In this way your original array will not be modified.

Comment: that would be less efficient, since a new copy will be created on every access.

Comment: @Eran I agree.. if I'm not wrong with due respect with your solution also `Arrays.asList(COLUMN_NAMES)` creates a new List each time right?

Comment: @ShubhenduPramanik yes, my static method suggestion has a similar issue. That's the reason I suggested an alternative without a static method.

Comment: @Shubhendu Pramanik Why return clone ? why not just return COLUMN_NAMES ?